# Intraday return and volatility figures some sense check

Tags: data, intraday, stylized-facts

Some questions about intraday returns and volatility figures. It is with the objective of sense checking.

Firstly, for Security A, I am calculating the five minute interval return numbers over 29500 intervals. You can see below some of the results.

Secondly, for another security, I am calculating the Parkinson volatility numbers using five minute intervals. I use the following Parkinson volatility
formula

[image]

I first calculate the parkinson numbers per each day and take the average of the days over 365 days.

**Return Numbers** for Security A at 5 minute intervals
    R_t(%) x 10^2   R_t(%)     |R_t| (%)    |R_t| (%)   R_t^2(%)    R_t^2(%)
    Mean    Standard Deviation  Mean    Standard Deviation  Mean    Standard Deviation
S   -0.0083           0.1166    0.0737     0.0903       0.0001         0.0007

**Volatility Numbers** for Security B at 5 minute intervals

*calculated per day
Average Vol (%) Std Dev   Minimum (%)   Maximum (%)
0.0737582      0.0312347    0.0290989   0.2561527

1) Do these return and volatility numbers make sense from a scale point of view? What source can guide us as to the stylized facts and expected scale of intraday return /volatility figures? Obviously, this will assure whether one's estimations are within reasonable ranges.The volatility numbers seem low to me.

2) The Parkinson volatility calculation as per the attached formula-what time horizon does it correspond to? daily? what is right frequency convention in the statement of intra-day volatility figures?

3) In terms of volatility conversion, how can one convert a 5 minute intraday volatility number into 30-min volatility numbers? Likewise into daily or annualized figures
Your prompt response will be appreciated

Comment: Any chance you could use TeX to cleanup the tables?

Comment: Return Numbers for Security A
                                                                                                                    mean: R_{t}x 10^{2} =-0.0083%
standard deviation  R_{t} : 0.1166 %


mean:\left |R_{t}  \right | =0.0737%
standard deviation:\left | R_{t}  \right |=0.0903%


mean: R_{t}^{2}=0.0001%
standard deviation: R_{t}^{2}=0.0007%

Comment: Security B Average Volatility (%)= 0.0737582 
Std Dev = 0.0312347
Minimum (%) =0.0290989
Maximum (%) =  0.2561527

Comment: I hope it is more legible now

Comment: Actually, I meant could you 'edit' your question, not put the corrections in comments.